# Member Variable Of Type String (Array) Pointer throwing Exception. (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have instantiated a private member variable in a 'Student' object. It points to an array that I'm dynamically resizing according to number of courses the 'student' is enrolled in.

I'm new to pointers, and I'm probably messing up something to do with the reference to the dynamically declared 'course' array in the heap.

**EDIT :** Vectors, Lists, or anything other than primitive std:string arrays can't be used.

The following line throws an exception:

```
void Student::addCourse(std::string course){
    numCourses++;

    std::string *tempArray = new std::string[numCourses];

    for(int i = 0; i <= numCourses - 1; i++){
        tempArray[i] = courseList[i]; // <---------- This line...
    }   
    tempArray[numCourses - 1] = course;

    courseList = tempArray;
    delete []tempArray;
}

Unhandled exception at 0x50A0E89A (msvcr110d.dll) in filename.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xABABABAB.
```

The member is declared like so in the header file:

```
class Student
{
private:
    std::string *courseList;
```

**EDIT :** Here's the constructor I'm using:

```
Student::Student(std::string name)
    :numCourses(0),
    courseList(nullptr),
    name(name){}
```

Any input is appreciated. 
Cheers.

Comment: Where is courseList allocated? What is its size? You are probably reading beyond its size in the for loop.

Comment: I kind of cant understand why you have pointer to std::string.
Btw from your code, you make `courseList` point to memory pointed by `tempArray` and then you delete the memory, which means `courseList` now points to freed heap memory

Comment: Hey @fhsilva, It's not an index out of bounds error. Good thought though!

Comment: @TheOne, I know that assignment line is horrid: VS 2012 wont allow a line like so: `*courseList = *tempArray;`

I want to copy `tempArray's` referenced objects into the location courseArray's referencing.

EDIT: Also, `courseArray` must be in the heep. I thought I was achieving that like this.

Comment: @TheOne is right. For example, if you call addCourse twice in a row, you will access invalid memory on the for loop, since courseList will be pointing to invalid memory. Actually after one call to addCourse, you can not use courseList anymore.
Why do you nee the temp array? Actually, why do you need pointers to std::string? Use a std::vector<std::string> and it will be better.

Comment: I wish I could use vectors. That's not an option either. The main objective is to dynamically create, and resize the (old school) std::string array in the heap at runtime. It's hard to wrap my head around because I'm certain I need to first create a pointer. Then on the construction of the student object, appoint it to a new Std::string array. I'll fix what you two have pointed out right now.

How's this?: `courseList = new std::string[numCourses];`

Comment: Revised:
`delete []courseList;
courseList = tempArray;`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a list, like:

```cpp
List<string> s = new List<string>();
```

Comment: That would be incredibly easy, and a lot less painful. I'm not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is wrong with your code is the `delete []tempArray;` and that is, because before that you make `courseList` point to the same address that `tempArray` points to, and then you delete memory stored within `tempArray`, which means that `courseList` now points to invalid(recycled, freed) memory.

You should make `courseList` nullptr(NULL if you don't have C++11-compilant compiler) when in constructor, and then the `Student::addCourse` can look like this:

```
void Student::addCourse(std::string course){
    numCourses++;

    std::string *tempArray = new std::string[numCourses];

    for(int i = 0; i < numCourses - 1; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = courseList[i];
    }   
    tempArray[numCourses - 1] = course;

    delete[] courseList;

    courseList = tempArray;
}
```

So basically you allocate new memory for the new sequence of strings, and then you assign the old contents from `courseList` into `tempArray`, then you assign the new `course` string into the last place, and you delete the old strings. After that you make `courseList` point to the same thing `tempArray` points to.

EDIT:

Changed the `-2` into `-1` as well as `<=` into `<`

Comment: Excellent. Although `-2` puts me out of bounds when I'm adding the first element.

Also, it's breaking at this line: `tempArray[i] = courseList[i]`

Can anyone see why?

Comment: oh yea, because 1 - 2 = -1. I changed it back to -1, but with < as condition, instead of <=

Comment: I got it, changing the constructor to initiate the array to a null value threw it. 

Thanks everyone!